# How to join the value coming in BLE notification in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, append, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm getting data in 20 bytes chunks in BLE notification. I'm converting that to string but I need to join all that strings together. This is my code

```
characteristicRead.ValueUpdated += (o, e) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //var readvalue2 = characteristics.Value;
                    var bytes = e.Characteristic.Value;
                    //var readvalue = await characteristics.ReadAsync();
                    BLEresultnew = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                    Console.WriteLine(BLEresultnew);
                    var termsList = new List<string>();
                    //var joinedStrings = termsList.Join(",");
                    termsList.Add(BLEresultnew);
                    concat = String.Join(" ", termsList.ToArray());
                    //int listdata=termsList.Count();
                    //string valuel = listdata.ToString();
                });
            };
            await characteristicRead.StartUpdatesAsync();
```

This is the data which is coming in logs which I need to join and display in a string or array.

```
01-07 13:07:07.340 I/mono-stdout( 4797): {"name":"Lime","stat
us":"Available"},{"n
01-07 13:07:07.448 I/mono-stdout( 4797): us":"Available"},{"n
ame":"Peach", "statu
01-07 13:07:07.568 I/mono-stdout( 4797): ame":"Peach", "statu
s":"Available"},{{"n
01-07 13:07:07.650 I/mono-stdout( 4797): s":"Available"},{{"n
```

I have tried string.Join but its not working. I have tried string builder but still it is not joining all the strings as you can see below.

```
Console.WriteLine(BLEresultnew);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(BLEresultnew);
                   //sb.Append(BLEresultnew);
                    concat= sb.Append(BLEresultnew).ToString();
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: you are creating a new, empty `termsList` every time - `var termsList = new List<string>();`

Comment: Your dump could be misleading. Are you sure no newline \n is included anywhere in your string BLEresultnew  ? All lines have the same max width. Any forced breaks on a certain width while reporting ?

Comment: you should probably be using `StringBuilder`

Comment: @Jason yes it is just adding string in  BLEresultnew   one by one but not storing it. it is changing.

Comment: that is because your are throwing away your previous results each time by creating a new object

Comment: @Jason I tried StringBuilder  it is not working. I have made changes in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is more efficient, but simply doing this should work (assuming `concat` is a class level variable)

```
concat += BLEresultnew;
```